# How to log everything in 'when' part of Drools rule?

Tags: java, logging, drools

I have to log everything that is responsible to fire a rule in Drools like objects, conditions etc.

I am able to get the objects by using **AgendaEventListener** and writing below code in the beforeActivationFired method of it.

```
@Override
public void beforeActivationFired(BeforeActivationFiredEvent event){
    event.getActivation().getObjects();
}
```

But how do I get the conditions and which methods are called on which object?
Like I have an object that is used as a global variable which is used to validate values against values in cache i.e. in **when** part of the rules different methods on this global object(have hundreds of methods in it) are called.

Now I want to have information on what methods are called so that I can log the information before hand because after the execution the values in the cache might get change.

**For example** -

If in when part below condition is there then I wish to know the condition as well as the value of both the sides in the condition i.e. the value of $val as well as $cache.getCurrentTimestamp()(Please note that the method called on cache is not known beforehand).

```
$val : timestamp,
$val == $cache.getCurrentTimestamp()
```

How can I achieve this task?

Comment: If it were possible and available, you'd be swamped in a heap of data where you'd have a hard time forming it into a sensible, digestible form. -- I suggest that you explain in some detail *why* you need this low-level data; perhaps s.o. can then suggest a way for writing rules that's really helpful.

Comment: I have already written set of rules and there are hundreds of drool files and it has become difficult to find where the bug is during the bug fix. So I want to ensure that if I try to replicate the issue on my local machine then I should get all the data because I will change the logging level on my machine and it would help me in identifying the bug.